# Are permissions transfered through multiple stages from AD?

Tags: permissions, active-directory, audience-targeting

I am setting up a SharePoint site where the security permissions are configured as follows:

Active directory security group: Users -> SharePoint (OU) -> WebAuthors
My user, geir, is a member of the "WebAuthors" security gorup.

SharePoint: "Web Authors" SP group at the root site has DOMAIN\WebAuthors as a member.
Subsite "Publishing" has permissions for "Web Authors" set to "Contribute".

By my logic, me (geir) should now have Contribute permission to the subsite publishing. For some reason, however, it seems I don't. I have tried setting [token-timeout to a smaller value](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287917%28office.12%29.aspx), to no avail. The reason I need to set up security like this is because the AD security group is supposed to be used as a Target Audience, and target audiences are by default not controlled against AD (due to performance issues, or so I read somewhere).

Does SharePoint in fact support what I am trying to do, or am I on a wild goose chase here?

[Edit: It seems that giving "DOMAIN\WebAuthors" Contribute permission directly doesn't work either. So apparently the data I need isn't transfered from AD in the first place.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD group membership is transfered to SharePoint in each request. But if you haven't been  logged out on your workstation after a group change has happend then you're transfering old information to SharePoint in each request. Windows only updates the list of groups on login.

Comment: This does the trick; thanks. Should have thought this was obvious, but appatently not.